# Select Different Div on JFlow Load

Tags: javascript

I am using JFlow for my content slider and would like to select one particular slide on page load. It can be the 5th slide or the second one but I don't want to re-order the slides.

Any ideas? [link text](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/step-by-step-to-create-content-slider-using-jflow-a-minimalist-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this, but need to change "jquery.flow.1.2.js" ti suit your requirement. Here is the updated file

For this existing defaults block with this one. Note last line with **startSlideNumber** variable

```
    $.fn.jFlow.defaults = {
        controller: ".jFlowControl", // must be class, use . sign
        slideWrapper : "#jFlowSlide", // must be id, use # sign
        selectedWrapper: "jFlowSelected",  // just pure text, no sign
        easing: "swing",
        duration: 400,
        width: "100%",
        prev: ".jFlowPrev", // must be class, use . sign
        next: ".jFlowNext", // must be class, use . sign
        startSlideNumber:0
    };
```

then change

```
var cur = 0; to

var cur = opts.startSlideNumber;
```

In your your main file, you can write, Here you can initialize **"startSlideNumber"** to your slide number [5th or second]. Remember 1st slide = 0

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myController").jFlow({
        slides: "#slides",
        controller: ".jFlowControl", // must be class, use . sign
        slideWrapper : "#jFlowSlide", // must be id, use # sign
        selectedWrapper: "jFlowSelected",  // just pure text, no sign
        auto: true,     //auto change slide, default true
        width: "610px",
        height: "235px",
        duration: 400,
        prev: ".jFlowPrev", // must be class, use . sign
        next: ".jFlowNext", // must be class, use . sign
        startSlideNumber:2
    });
});
```